# How to prevent a repeat of a program call within a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to prevent this switch function from constantly repeating within the probability while loop, i want it to be called once promoting an input and then using the return of that input for each time in the while loop instead of asking every time
[Click here to see screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqV9v.png)

(it won't let me add a second picture of the switch function so ill just copy and paste it)

```
def switch_door():
    switch=raw_input("Switch doors?:")
    if switch!="y" and switch!="n":
        return "Incorrect inputs"
    elif switch=='y':
        return True 
    elif switch=='n':
        return False
```

Comment: paste your code in your question. And your formatting is off

Comment: set a variable equal to the output of switch_door function outside your while loop and pass that variable to the simulation function.

Comment: If you want to only ask once for the user input for `Switch doors` then why not just put it with the rest of your inputs before your while loop?

Comment: You should **always** copy and paste your code, not only when you cannot add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You may set a variable e.g.`if_switch=switch_door()` in the `probability()` function *before your while loop* and pass that variable to your simulation function as a parameter. 
Note that you will need to change your simulation definition to e.g. `def simulation(doors, if_switch):`; you will also need to change these two lines:

1. `if switch_door()==True:` to `if if_switch==True:`
2. `elif switch_door()==False:` to simply `else:`

Now your problem should solved.